# Working backwards through a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to figure out how to work through a list in reverse order (back to front) in Scheme using recursion. My research shows that there is a reverse function that you can use on a list but I would not like to go that route.

I know that the following returns the last element in a list;

```
(caddr '(1 5 3))
returns 3
```

I would like to be able to send the remaining 1 5 back through the function, look at the last element again and repeat until the list is exhausted

From left to right is simple enough, you look at the car of the list and send back the cdr.

Comment: Break down the problem in the base step, the recursive step and what order they go in. Hint: If you first do the recursive step, then the base, you'd recurse through the entire list and then handle the base case, and then do the remaining elements as the stack unwinds.

Comment: The function `caddr` does not return the last element in 'a list'; it returns the last element in 'your list'.

Comment: What is wrong with `reverse`?

Answer (score 2):

Do the recursive call first, then the processing of the `car`. Example:

```
(define (process-in-reverse lst fun)
  (when (not (null? lst))
    (process-in-reverse (cdr lst) fun)
    (fun (car lst))))
```

then

```
> (process-in-reverse '(1 5 3) display)
351
```

If you just want to reverse the *result* and if subsequent calls are independent of previous calls, an accumulator will do and is tail-recursive:

```
(define (process-reverse-result lst fun)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        res
        (loop (cdr lst) 
              (cons (fun (car lst)) res)))))
```

then

```
> (process-reverse-result '(1 5 3) add1)
'(4 6 2)
```

Comment: ppl in [tag:scheme] should really upvote each other more. If not us, then who? this is a good answer, why wasn't it upvoted until now?